# .htaccess, how to force stop any redirects? Even if we could not access Cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, redirect

good morning, i need your help please.

our site `-----.com` is redirecting to an unknown site `----.com`
how to force stop that redirect using .htaccess?

the problem is that we can't access our Cpanel
because our hosting provider does not renewed it or something like that we don't know
when we login to our Cpanel this message appears

```
Cannot read license file. To access the interface, you must install the license and ensure that the license is active. This server does not have a valid license. To address this issue, you must contact your hosting provider. After you successfully activate the license, reload the page and the message will no longer display.
```

and we tried to call him alot but he does not response

we need to stop that redirect to take a backup from our mysql databases using php script

I hope that I described my problem well, PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Depending on how the redirect is implemented, that may or may not be possible. Do you currently have an `.htaccess` file and if so what is in it?

Comment: i accessed my site using ftp and moved all my site folders to a new folder and deleted the old `.htaccess` file and created a new one and tried a lot of `RewriteRule` codes but nothing work. i have the ability to access and edit my `.htaccess` file.  my current htaccess file contains `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/backup.php$
RewriteRule $ /backup.php [R=302,L]`

Comment: If all you want is the data from the database and you can connect via FTP, you may be able to work out the old IP address of the server and access it directly. What address do you use to connect to your FTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your domain DNS records point to 4chill.com [SOURCE](http://centralops.net/co/) I'd say that without your hosts support your data is inaccessible. Contact the person hosting your MySQL data and ask for a export of the schemas.

Comment: You cannot fix this issue yourself, You need to sort it out with your host. This is not a question we can help you with.

Comment: Sorry for that! but we can't reach him. so what can we do?? i need help so i ask experts like you!

Comment: You can't do anything, Its entirely up to your host to fix it. Contact them through their website, email, every means that you have available.

Answer (score 2):

It look like your domain is redirected on DNS level:

> Name Server: NS1.4CHILL.COM
>   Name Server: NS2.4CHILL.COM
>   [whois record](http://www.whois.com/whois/youthmediaf.com)

so it means it's not pointing to your server anymore and changing `.htaccess` won't solve your problem.
If domain wasn't renewed and has new owner, contact with your hosting provider to clarify what's happened.